Is it possible to create a dymamic array which sums different columns depending on row?
I know how to use BYROW(), CHOOSECOLS() and LAMBDA() etc. to sum up columns.
e.g.
=BYROW(CHOOSECOLS(B2:M3,1,2,3,4,5,6),LAMBDA(a,SUM(a)))

I would like to sum up columns but the columns to be summed up would be different in each row depending on a a cell in that row
e.g. in row 1, I want to sum up columns 1,2,3,4 but in row 2 I want to sum up 5,6,7,8,9,10,11 and 12
I was thinking something along the lines of:
=BYROW(b2:m3,LAMBDA(a,SUM(CHOOSECOLS(a,TEXTSPLIT(A2,","))))) 

where A2 would have 1,2,3,4 and A3 would have 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
However this does not work
Is this possible?

Pretty simple use the whole range in BYROW() function, TAKE() the first column while for sum DROP() the first col:


=BYROW(A2:M3,LAMBDA(α,SUM(CHOOSECOLS(DROP(α,,1),--TEXTSPLIT(TAKE(α,,1),",")))))



Just add -- to convert the result from TEXTSPLIT to number

=LAMBDA(csv_col_nums, range_to_sum,
    BYROW(
        csv_col_nums,
        LAMBDA(r,
            LET(
                row_num, ROW(r) -
                    MIN(ROWS(csv_col_nums)) + 1,
                SUM(
                    CHOOSECOLS(
                        INDEX(range_to_sum, row_num, ),
                        --TEXTSPLIT(r, ",")
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)(A2:A3, B2:M3)


Thank you @nkalvi This is certainly further than I had got. However, the second row is calculating as 23 which is the sum of the first 4 columns again, whereas for that row, I need the sum of the last 8 columns (46)

Please see my update.

using your latest screenshot, I would like the first number in the array created to be 26: 6+3+10+7 (the first 4 numbers on the first row)
and the second number to be 42: 7+1+3+4+10+7+9+1 (the last 8 numbers of the last row)

@andyleary see my answer what you need to do, the setup you have just makes it more dynamic and powerful. Nice setup and idea. You will need to TAKE() fist col for split and DROP() for col for SUM(). Basic understanding of BYROW(). when using BYROW() for SUM() use the whole range and do the same within the custom calculations using LET() or directly.

@andy, please try the update when you get a chance. With this, columns numbers can be anywhere or even a constant {"1,2","3,6"} (need to have the same number of rows though).

@MayukhBhattacharya  do you know why the formulas wouldn't work wen I reference an array as opposed to range:
=BYROW(FILTER($a$2:$m$3,$n$2:$n$5="yes"),LAMBDA(α,SUM(CHOOSECOLS(DROP(α,,1),--TEXTSPLIT(TAKE(α,,1),",")))))
it seems to be taking the first referenced column in each case i.e. first and 5th respectively

@andyleary this is a different question, could you make a new post, since as per SO, per post one question. I try to adhere the rules! But since its related i will update you asap!

@Mayukh Bhattacharya. Sorry, I am new to this. Thank you. I have done
